# cannot catch the exception more than one time

Tags: java, exception

when running the code, if I input any character other than number, the exeception "java.util.InputMismatchException" gets catched, but next time if I input any character other than number, the program gets terminated with error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException". how to make it able to catch more than one simultaneous exceptions untill a valid input is given.

```
/*
Twenty students were asked to rate on a scale of 1 to 5 the quality of the food in the
student cafeteria, with 1 being “awful” and 5 being “excellent.” Place the 20 responses
in an integer array and determine the frequency of each rating.
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentPoll 
{
    static Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Rate the quality of food from 1 to 5." +
                "\n1 being “awful” and 5 being “excellent”.\n");
        int[] array=new int[10];
        int num =0;
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {

            do{
                System.out.println("Student "+(i+1)+" Enter Your Response:");
                try
                {
                    num=input.nextInt();
                }
                catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter numbers only.");
                    input.nextLine();
                    num=input.nextInt();
                }   
                if(num<=0 || num>5)

                {
                    System.out.println("Enter 1 to 5 only.");
                }
            }while(num<=0 || num>5);
            array[i]=num;

        }

        int[] frequency=new int[6];

        for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
        {
            frequency[array[i]]=frequency[array[i]]+1;      
        }

        System.out.printf("*    :%d (awful)\n",frequency[1]);
        System.out.printf("**   :%d\n",frequency[2]);
        System.out.printf("***  :%d\n",frequency[3]);
        System.out.printf("**** :%d\n",frequency[4]);
        System.out.printf("*****:%d (excellent)\n",frequency[5]);
    }
}`
```

Comment: You're requesting numeric input again in your catch block, why?

Comment: If i dont request numeric input, then the response from ith student gets skipped.

Comment: So what you have here is a different issue, the 'fix' for which is causing the problem that you're posting about. Every point that you call `Scanner#nextInt()` has the potential to throw an `InputMismatchException` - the one inside your `catch` block isn't caught by anything.

Comment: Then what should I do @JonK

Comment: You need two loops - an outer loop to iterate through all of the students, and an inner loop to keep prompting for numeric input until it gets a valid number, which can then be passed back to the outer loop to be used. You're actually not too far off with what you currently have - you just need to separate what your two loops are doing. You might find it helpful to pull all of the code for requesting input into a new method that simply returns the valid number.

Comment: @JonK, can you update the code for me??

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not have another try-catch statement in your catch statement, you can just re-run the loop if you want to catch the exception again. So you would replace:

```
catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e)
{
    System.out.println("Enter numbers only.");
    input.nextLine();
    num = input.nextInt();
}
```

with:

```
catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e)
{
    System.out.println("Enter numbers only.");
    input.nextLine();
    continue;
}
```

Comment: continue statement just skips the other inputs. It will not work.

Comment: It's a loop, the continue statement will make it recheck the input.

Comment: Yes i understand that but in this case the other inputs gets skipped. you can check it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Because when first exception occur in the try block that is caught by the catch block. And if the user again give a invalid input then again the exception thrown. But there is no mechanism in your code to catch that exception. Therefore the main thread stopped. Catch block will not responsible to catch exception that is throw inside that block.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentPoll
{
static Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Rate the quality of food from 1 to 5." +
            "\n1 being “awful” and 5 being “excellent”.\n");
    int[] array=new int[10];
    int num =0;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {

        do{
            System.out.println("Student "+(i+1)+" Enter Your Response:");
            try
            {
                num=input.nextInt();
            }
            catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e)
            {
                input.next(); // consume the leftover new line
                System.out.println("Enter numbers only.");
            }
            if(num<=0 || num>5)

            {
                System.out.println("Enter 1 to 5 only.");
            }

        }while(num<1 || num>5); // change in the logic
        array[i]=num;

    }

    int[] frequency=new int[6];

    for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
    {
        frequency[array[i]]=frequency[array[i]]+1;
    }

    System.out.printf("*    :%d (awful)\n",frequency[1]);
    System.out.printf("**   :%d\n",frequency[2]);
    System.out.printf("***  :%d\n",frequency[3]);
    System.out.printf("**** :%d\n",frequency[4]);
    System.out.printf("*****:%d (excellent)\n",frequency[5]);
}
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean to say, but your edit makes it more worse. It will not read further input.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but still it will not work. You can check it with both valid and invalid inputs. It will give unexpected output.

Comment: @kailash [see](https://postimg.org/image/9i2ysg6u3/) this is the output I am getting.

Comment: Yes there is error. At student 3 you entered ew. without accepting valid input from student 3, now input option goes to student 4. And 5 was entered by student 6 only but in output, it shows "*****: 2". which means two students voted 5. But in real only one student voted 5. Anyway i got the answer. Thanks for your effort to help me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem statements is after the wrong input the program doesn't wait for next user input
You can achieve this my accepting the input via java.util.Scanner & making for loop within do while.

try the below code it should work as per your need.

```
/*
Twenty students were asked to rate on a scale of 1 to 5 the quality of the food in the
student cafeteria, with 1 being “awful” and 5 being “excellent.” Place the 20 responses
in an integer array and determine the frequency of each rating.
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentPoll  {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Rate the quality of food from 1 to 5."
                + "\n1 being “awful” and 5 being “excellent”.\n");
        int[] array = new int[10];
        int num = 0;

        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Student " + (i + 1)
                        + " Enter Your Response:");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                try {
                    num = sc.nextInt();
                } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Enter numbers only.");
                    num = 0;
                    --i;
                    continue;
                }
                if (num <= 0 || num > 5) {
                    System.out.println("Enter 1 to 5 only.");
                    num = 0;
                    --i;
                    continue;
                }
                array[i] = num;
            }
        } while (num <= 0 || num > 5);


        int[] frequency = new int[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            frequency[array[i]] = frequency[array[i]] + 1;
        }

        System.out.printf("*    :%d (awful)\n", frequency[1]);
        System.out.printf("**   :%d\n", frequency[2]);
        System.out.printf("***  :%d\n", frequency[3]);
        System.out.printf("**** :%d\n", frequency[4]);
        System.out.printf("*****:%d (excellent)\n", frequency[5]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the edit will not work. After exception gets handled, the response from ith student will not get registered.In the code, I want the response from each student to get registered.

Comment: updated my answer based on your comment, it will now make sure it registers all 10 inputs